# Will selecting from pg_locks always return a result for itself?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

`SELECT relation::regclass, * FROM pg_locks ;`

Results in the following:

```
 relation |  locktype  | database | relation | page | tuple | virtualxid | transactionid | classid | objid | objsubid | virtualtransaction | pid  |      mode       | granted | fastpath 
 ----------+------------+----------+----------+------+-------+------------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+--------------------+------+-----------------+---------+----------
 pg_locks | relation   |    16397 |    11187 |      |       |            |               |         |       |          | 76/111628          | 2652 | AccessShareLock | t       | t
      | virtualxid |          |          |      |       | 76/111628  |               |         |       |          | 76/111628          | 2652 | ExclusiveLock   | t       | t
 (2 rows)
```

Can I assume that my query of `pg_locks` is itself what is causing the `ExclusiveLock` in that result?

Comment: Yes, those locktypes are from your query. You'll note that the exclusive lock is on a virtual transaction id, which is assigned for the duration of your transaction (in this case, for you query against the pg_locks relation).  [9.4 docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/view-pg-locks.html)

Comment: @bma You should convert your comment to an answer.